# how to get count by key in Python dictionary

Tags: python

Have been working on a python dictionary for many hours and still cant figure this out.

```
dict_1 = {'A': ['a','b','b','c','c','c'], 'B':['1','2','2','1','2','3']}
```

I wish to get the count of unique values in the key B by key A. For example, the value 'a' in A has value '1' in B, resulted in one unique count; value 'b' in A has value '2' and '2' in B, resulted in one unique count; value 'c' in A has value '1', '2', '3' in B, resulted in three unique counts.

How do I get the following output:

```
{'A' : ['a','b','c'], 'unique_count_B' : ['1','1','3']}
```

Where should I start?
Thanks!

Comment: `print({'A' : ['a','b','c'], 'unique_count_B' : ['1','1','3']})` would give you the output... but you should probably at least explain the rules better

Comment: could you clarified the question? the question still quite confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I get it. You can do something like this:

Use zip to loop through the lists at the same time.

Use a dictionary to map each letter to a set of integers.

Convert the set to a length value at the end

```
A = ['a','b','b','c','c','c']
B = ['1','2','2','1','2','3']

mapping = {}
for a, b in zip(A, B):
    if a not in mapping:
        mapping[a] = set()
    mapping[a].add(b)

length_mapping = {}
for a, b_vals in mapping.items():
    length_mapping[a] = len(b_vals)

print(list(length_mapping.keys()))
print(list(length_mapping.values()))
```

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
[1, 1, 3]
```

Using some fancy helpers

```
from collections import defaultdict

A = ['a','b','b','c','c','c']
B = ['1','2','2','1','2','3']

mapping = defaultdict(set)
for a, b in zip(A, B):
    mapping[a].add(b)

print(list(mapping.keys()))
print(list(map(len, mapping.values())))
```

Comment: yes. thank you this is exactly what I want. How can I be a master in python like you? I am such a noob.

Comment: @Iwishworldpeace haha thank you for the nice words, although I would not say I've mastered it!. My advice; be aware that there's always more to learn, and drink lots of coffee :P

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. It's totally fine.